Remove python pillow image comment
Since upgrading python3 pillow to version 10.3.0, I have found that when resizing an image it adds a comment inside my .jpgs that never used to be there (vs. a year or so ago, but I don't know the old version number).
The comment inside the image looks like this:
CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 90

or
CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 70

I version my images in a repository and I don't want them changing if there was actually no change. Doing a diff I can see this is the only change.
Is there a way to suppress this comment from ending up in the .jpg when using pillow?
Here is the code I am using:
import PIL

img_original = PIL.Image.open("original_image.jpg")
new_img = img_original.resize(
    (200, 200), # width, height
    PIL.Image.LANCZOS
)
new_img.save("new_image.jpg")

Update
Apologies! I have had time to do some digging and found that the above CREATOR... strings are actually present in the original jpg images. So PIL is not to blame. Sorry for the wild goose chase. My original images are being downloaded from a third party that has modified only some of them recently to include CREATOR.... And I found 100% correlation between the resized images that contain CREATOR... and the original images that contain CREATOR....
So that resolves the question. I don't mind if someone wants to delete it. Or happy to leave it up.
As an aside, I did find that implementing @Kozydot's changes (new_img.save("new_image.jpg", quality=90)) did not cause pillow to remove the CREATOR... string from the resized images. But that is not a requirement for me now anyway.

Linux Mint 21.2 Xfce, Python 3.12 , pillow 10.3.0 : can't see in the created .jpg image file content any comment like CREATOR: ... . Same on Python 3.10.

On my system import PIL and usage of PIL.Image.open() fails AttributeError: module 'PIL' has no attribute 'Image' . I need to use: from PIL import Image instead. Are you sure you are using what you mean to use?

What do you get if you run: pip install pillow? How do you run the script?

@Claudio i'mm using virtualenv so $ pip install pillow outputs Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /home/me/project/lib/python3.11/site-packages (10.3.0)

Hmmm ... Which system are you using? There need be a reason why you experience this issue where I can't reproduce it and need from PIL import Image as import PIL leads to an error ... P.S. I have the same output on pip install pillow as you and tested on Python 10 and 12.

@Claudio i'm on debian bookworm but i'd be surprised if that made a difference. When I use the python command-line it imports PIL ok: `$ python3
Python 3.11.2 (main, Mar 13 2023, 12:18:29) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.



import PIL
 Note also that  i have usedpip install image` also. That may make a difference I'm not sure.




@Claudio i was already motivated to solve this problem. this is to build my blog, which i wanted to get running again this weekend

Normally PIL will carry forward comments and metadata from input images into its output images. You can see this very easily if you create a JPEG with a comment - I'll use ImageMagick and check it with exiftool:
magick -comment "Built-in comment" xc: input.jpg

Then check it with:
exiftool -s3 -comment input.jpg                     
Built-in comment


So, let's load that image with a comment into PIL and save:
from PIL import Image

# Load the image with comment
im = Image.open('input.jpg')

# Save the image - propagating the comment forward
im.save(result.jpg')

Now check the comment is still there:
exiftool -s3 -comment result.jpg
Built-in comment

Now force null comment with PIL and resave:
im.save('result.jpg', comment=None)

And check that no comment is saved:
exiftool -s3 -comment result.jpg       # no output, i.e. no comments


Note that if you have already done a load of work and edited your images and they already inadvertently now contain comments, you can simply delete the comments without decompressing/recompressing or otherwise changing the file using exiftool:
exiftool -comment= image.jpg


You can explicitly set the quality parameter in the save method. This parameter controls the quality of the output image on a scale from 1 (worst) to 95 (best). By setting this parameter, you can avoid the automatic addition of the comment about the creator and quality settings.
import PIL

img_original = PIL.Image.open("original_image.jpg")
new_img = img_original.resize(
    (200, 200), # width, height
    PIL.Image.LANCZOS
)
new_img.save("new_image.jpg", quality=90) # Set the quality parameter


See my comment to the question. Could you reproduce the issue on your system? With what result?

i think this works but i need to debug a bit more - tomorrow
